# Central Limit Theorem and Uniform Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

How does central limit theorem hold good for uniform distribution? Suppose $p(x)$ for $x=1,2,3…,n$ be $1/n$. If we take a sample say $1,2,3$ the mean is $2$ but since it is uniform the probability value will be $1/n$ isn’t it? And the same for all samples, how does this look a normal curve when the number of samples increase?

Comment: The sample mean will certainly not be uniformly distributed.  If you take $1000$ samples from your fixed set, the mean of those samples is much more likely to be  near $\frac {n+1}2$ than near  $1$ or near $n$.

Comment: Can you illustrate with a simple example?

Comment: Sure...take the simples example.  Bernoulli trial  $0,1$ with equal chance.  Same as tossing a fair coin and counting the Heads.  A big sample of coin tosses gives a normal distribution for the number of Heads.  Similarly, the sum of the faces shown on repeat tosses of a fair die approaches a normal.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what happens when everything is a uniform distribution on $\{0, 1\}$.

If there's just one, then the possible values are 0 and 1, and they're all equally likely, so $P(U_1 = 0) = P(U_1 = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$.

If you have two variables, then the possible values of their sum are in the range of 0 to 2, but they aren't evenly distributed because $U_1 + U_2 = 2$ only if $U_1 = U_2 = 1$ so it has a probability of $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$, but $U_1 + U_2 = 1$ can happen in 2 different ways - 0+1 and 1+0, so it has a probability of $2 \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$.

So the probabilities become:

| $u$ | Ways to sum | $P(U_1 + U_2 = u)$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0+0 | $\frac{1}{4}$ |
| 1 | 0+1, 1+0 | $\frac{2}{4}$ |
| 2 | 1+1 | $\frac{1}{4}$ |

When you get to 3 variables, it looks like this:

| $u$ | Ways to sum | $P(U_1 + U_2 + U_3 = u)$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0+0+0 | $\frac{1}{8}$ |
| 1 | 0+0+1, 0+1+0, 1+0+0 | $\frac{3}{8}$ |
| 2 | 0+1+1, 1+0+1, 1+1+0 | $\frac{3}{8}$ |
| 3 | 1+1+1 | $\frac{1}{8}$ |

You can see what happens for even more variables by playing with [this Binomial Distribution visualisation](https://shiny.rit.albany.edu/stat/binomial/), set "Probability of success" to 0.5 and adjust "Number of trials". When you increase that value, you'll see it become more and more bell-curve-like.